# When I use a sqlite database as an asset can the database still be used/viewed by another program?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on my capstone and I need to create two programs using two different languages that use a single local database. I am making a  chore manager that will be a windows program and an android app. I figure out how to use sqlite for the windows app, but I cannot wrap my head around using an existing database with android studio. I need the app to be able to read existing data and display it and then based on some conditions edit the data.

If I add the database as an asset will the data a user changes using the app be usable by another windows program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my opinion:  "Don't use SQLite for this."  Use a regular shared database that you can *(securely ...)* access from both environments.

SQLite databases are *files,* accessed through the file-system.  They are most commonly used where the data won't be shared, because, like any "shared file" database of aeons past, they are always subject to corruption if someone (or the operating system, or the network ...) does anything wrong.  Whereas a conventional client/server database doesn't have these problems because it controls the data while it *talks* to you.

SQLite is a marvelous tool for storing structured information on a device.  I've deployed many dozens of "boutique" websites which store their page-information that way.  But, I think, it's not the right tool for *this* job.

Comment: So if I use Microsoft sql server, doesn't that mean that I either have to host it or the user(my professor) will have to have that manager installed on their pc?